# setting values after viewcontroller has loaded

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, nsstring, protocols

I am wondering how or if it is possible to reload a whole view some how as I am reciving a NSString I would like to display on the UIView but because the data is coming from a protocol/delegate thats initialized in another class and not the view that will become a sub view.. I am unable to get this NSString to show in the text label because the ViewController has already loaded before the data is squirted into the delegate/protocol.. this is my code its simple as.... I need to figure out how to reload the view or pass the value across to the view before it loads.

```
//These methods are declared inside ConnectionResponses.h as delegates to pass informatin to this view from ConnectioneResponses.
- (void)sendSeriesSearchArray:(NSArray *)array seriesToolBar:(NSString *)seriesToolBarString
{
    int arrayCount = [array count];
    NSLog(@"%i", arrayCount);


    manufactureToolBarLabel.text = seriesToolBarString;

}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController.m , add code when init:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) name:@"ValueChanged" object:nil];
```

in your delegate/protocol add code when some property changed:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ValueChanged" object:nil];
```

Then in method doSomething: you can change UI as you want.